# How to rewrite following rx-java crawler

Tags: java, rx-java

The crawler has a urlQueue to record urls to crawl, a mock asynchronous url fetcher.
I try to write it in rx-java style.
At first, I try Flowable.generate like this

```
    Flowable.generate((Consumer<Emitter<Integer>>) e -> {
        final Integer poll = demo.urlQueue.poll();
        if (poll != null) {
            e.onNext(poll);
        } else if (runningCount.get() == 0) {
            e.onComplete();
        }
    }).flatMap(i -> {
        runningCount.incrementAndGet();
        return demo.urlFetcher.asyncFetchUrl(i);
    }, 10)
            .doOnNext(page -> demo.onSuccess(page))
            .subscribe(page -> runningCount.decrementAndGet());
```

but it won't work, because at beginning, there may be only one seed in urlQueue, so generate is called 10 times, but only one e.onNext is emitted. Only when it is finished, then next request(1)-> generate is called.
Although in the code, we specify flatMap maxConcurrency is 10, it will crawl one by one.

After that , I modify code like following, It can work like expected.
But In the code, I should care how many tasks are running currently, then calculate how many should be fetched from the queue, that I think rx-java should do this job.

I am not sure if the code can be rewritten in a simpler way.

```
public class CrawlerDemo {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrawlerDemo.class);

    // it can be redis queue or other queue
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> urlQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private static AtomicInteger runningCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private static final int MAX_CONCURRENCY = 5;

    private UrlFetcher urlFetcher = new UrlFetcher();

    private void addSeed(int i) {
        urlQueue.offer(i);
    }

    private void onSuccess(Page page) {
        page.links.forEach(i -> {
            logger.info("offer more url " + i);
            urlQueue.offer(i);
        });
    }

    private void start(BehaviorProcessor processor) {
        final Integer poll = urlQueue.poll();
        if (poll != null) {
            processor.onNext(poll);

        } else {
            processor.onComplete();
        }
    }

    private int dispatchMoreLink(BehaviorProcessor processor) {

        int links = 0;
        while (runningCount.get() <= MAX_CONCURRENCY) {
            final Integer poll = urlQueue.poll();
            if (poll != null) {
                processor.onNext(poll);

                links++;
            } else {
                if (runningCount.get() == 0) {
                    processor.onComplete();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return links;
    }

    private Flowable<Page> asyncFetchUrl(int i) {
        return urlFetcher.asyncFetchUrl(i);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CrawlerDemo demo = new CrawlerDemo();
        demo.addSeed(1);

        BehaviorProcessor<Integer> processor = BehaviorProcessor.create();

        processor
                .flatMap(i -> {
                    runningCount.incrementAndGet();
                    return demo.asyncFetchUrl(i)
                            .doFinally(() -> runningCount.decrementAndGet())
                            .doFinally(() -> demo.dispatchMoreLink(processor));
                }, MAX_CONCURRENCY)
                .doOnNext(page -> demo.onSuccess(page))
                .subscribe();

        demo.start(processor);


    }


}

class Page {
    public List<Integer> links = new ArrayList<>();
}

class UrlFetcher {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UrlFetcher.class);


    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public Flowable<Page> asyncFetchUrl(Integer url) {

        logger.info("start async get " + url);
        return Flowable.defer(() -> emitter ->
                scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> {

                    Page page = new Page();
                    // the website urls no more than 1000
                    if (url < 1000) {
                        page.links = IntStream.range(1, 5).boxed().map(j -> 10 * url + j).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    }

                    logger.info("finish async get " + url);
                    emitter.onNext(page);
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));                                 // cost 5 seconds to access url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use regular (non-Rx) code with RxJava and not getting the results you want.

The first thing to do is to convert the `urlQueue.poll()` into a `Flowable<Integer>`:

```
Flowable.generate((Consumer<Emitter<Integer>>) e -> {
    final Integer take = demo.urlQueue.take(); // Note 1
    e.onNext(take); // Note 2
})
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), 1) // Note 3
    .flatMap(i -> demo.urlFetcher.asyncFetchUrl(i), 10)
    .subscribe(page -> demo.onSuccess(page));
```

1. Reading the queue in a reactive way means a blocking wait. Trying to `poll()` the queue adds a layer of complexity that RxJava allows you to skip over.
2. Pass the received value on to any subscribers. If you need to indicate completion, you will need to add an external boolean, or use an in-band indicator (such as a negative integer).
3. `observeOn()` operator will subscribe to the generator. The value `1` will cause only one subscription since there is no point in having more than one.

The rest of the code is similar to what you have. The issues that you have arose because the `flatMap(...,10)` operation will subscribe to the generator 10 times, which is not what you wanted. You want to limit the number of simultaneous fetches. Adding the `runningCount` was a kludge to prevent exiting the generator early, but it is not a substitute for a proper way to signal end-of-data on the `urlQueue`.